# How do I insert parentheses and slashes into MySQL

Tags: mysql

Im trying to escape both parentheses using MySQL. It's giving me an error starting at A.T.

```
INSERT INTO `schools`(`schoolid`, `name`) VALUES (1,"A.T. Still University of Health Sciences(AZ / MO)")
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need to "escape" anything in that statement.  You just need to use single-quotes for strings in SQL:

```
'A.T. Still University of Health Sciences(AZ / MO)'
```

It looks like double-quotes *can be* supported in MySQL, [depending on the `ANSI_QUOTES` setting](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-literals.html).  But unless there's a compelling reason to use them, I'd recommend sticking with single-quotes as it's more standard and more commonly used.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use single quotes for strings instead of double quotes. Try this:

```
INSERT INTO `schools`(`schoolid`, `name`) 
VALUES (1,'A.T. Still University of Health Sciences(AZ / MO)')
```

**[SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a1151)**

Answer (score 2):

Use **Special Character Escape Sequences** in the Insert statement

Escape Sequence Character Represented by Sequence

1. \0  An ASCII NUL (0x00) character
2. \'  A single quote (“'”) character
3. \"  A double quote (“"”) character
4. \b  A backspace character
5. \n  A newline (linefeed) character
6. \r  A carriage return character
7. \t  A tab character
8. \Z  ASCII 26 (Control+Z); see note following the table
9. \  A backslash (“\”) character
10. \% A “%” character; see note following the table
11. _ A “_” character; see note following the table